# Is there a portable Perl?

Tags: perl, portability, portable-applications

Is there a portable Perl  along the lines of portable Python? Something I could use (while learning the stuff) from my thumb drive?

Oh, and I'm talking about Window XP.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I can heartily recommend [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).

The Portable version is on Beta (the real meaning of Beta, though), click [here](http://strawberryperl.com/download/strawberry-perl-5.10.0.4-portable-beta-2.zip) to get it.

EDIT: The Portable version is already out of beta (for a few months now), check [here](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html)

Comment: Looks interesting, yes. Funny thing is, I don't remember seeing that the last time I visited the Strawberry's site ('twas a few months ago, though).

Comment: shoot, and I was going to propose Ubuntu on a thumbdrive!

Comment: The Strawberry Perl links are dead. Has the URL changed?

Answer (score 6):

There's a test version over at [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/node/12595) although it appears that long-term it will be replaced by [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) (which is what it's based on).

Answer (score 6):

I've deployed applications to hostile end user machines (i.e. machines I have no control over and no admin password) using Portable Strawberry Perl 5.10 with no problems.  For development work in windows you might want [this](http://szabgab.com/blog/2008/11/1228059107.html)