# Is Tinyperl dead?

Tags: perl, portable-executable

I'm looking for a light and portable perl release and found this one, but it seems there is no activity since 2003, which could be ok for me but I want to know if there is known issues.

So, if you can provide me some feedbacks, you're wellcome :)

Comment: It might help if you would explain exactly what the problem is you're trying to solve, not just what tool you're looking for to solve it with. :)

Comment: I'm seeking a script engine in order to make script :), 'cause .bat is really poor, I want to be able to do actions everywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, the best way to make distributable Perl scripts for Windows systems is to use a packager like [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PAR%3a%3aPacker) or [ActiveState's PerlApp](http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit).

Of course this only works if you don't need to do anything on the fly.  But it works really well if you have a collection of scripts that you want to move around and use on many systems.

Answer (score 4):

As a replacement for `.bat` files, as you indicate in your comments, I have found that I can install enough CPAN modules with [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) to make more-or-less cross-platform Perl scripts.

Answer (score 4):

See also [Is there a portable Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936185/is-there-a-portable-perl) which points to [the portable version of Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html)

There is also a [Portable Perl from PortableApps](http://portableapps.com/node/22980)

NB: I have used neither one