# CPAN Issues on Windows XP

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I'm suppose to do an install of a few Perl modules on a Windows box. This is a customer UAT box, so I have no idea how it was configured or by who. We did the install on the Dev box, and everything worked as advertised.

The box is running Cygwin, and it has Perl 5.8.8 installed. I can't update it or reinstall Cygwin. I have to use what I have.

I tried installing Spreadsheet::Read on the system, and got the following error:

```
  CPAN.pm: Going to build F/FD/FDALY/Test-Tester-0.107.tar.gz

 Checking if your kit is complete...
 Looks good
 Unable to find a perl 5 (by these names: /usr/bin/perl.exe perl.exe perl5.exe pe
 rl5.8.7.exe miniperl.exe, in these dirs: /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/X11R6
 /bin /cygdrive/d/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1/bin /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
 /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem /usr/bin /cygdrive/d/APPL
 IC~1/MCAFEE~1 /cygdrive/d/Applications/PowerCenter8.6.1/server/bin /usr/lib/lap
```

What? It couldn't find Perl 5? There it is right there in `/usr/bin/perl.exe` in Cygwin!

There's also an issue with make, but one thing at a time... gcc is installed on Cygwin, so that's not an issue.

What in the heck is going on? I do have .cpan in `/cygdrive/p/.cpan`, but that's because my `HOME` directory is defined there. (It's a corporate thing).

Any idea?

I need to install `Spreadsheet::Read`, `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, and `Spreadsheet::XLSX`. Is it possible to munge the installation if CPAN doesn't do it's thing, or is there compiled stuff required? Remember, Make is also acting up.

---

> Any chance you can use Strawberry Perl and leave the Cygwin headaches behind?

I've already asked. The answer is no.

> You say you have 5.8.8 but it is looking for perl5.8.7.exe. Post the $PATH.

It's Perl 5.8.7. My bad.

Path:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/X11R6/bin
/cygdrive/d/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1/bin
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
/cygdrive/c/System32/Wbem
/usr/bin
/cygdrive/d/APPLIC~1/MFAFEE~1
/cygdrive/d/ApplicationsPowerCenter8.6.1/server/bin
/usr/lib/lapack
```

> Did you check what condition actually displays that message?

There wasn't much of a condition. It downloaded everything then that message.

> What's the output of perl -le'print( (-x "/usr/bin/perl.exe") || 0 )'

You win: The permissions were `-rwx------`. I can't believe I missed that.

> What's the output of /usr/bin/perl.exe -e "require 5; print qq{VER_OK\n}" – ikegami 1 hour ago

VER_OK

---

For some reason, I was able to execute /usr/bin/perl, and certainly CPAN had to (isn't it a Perl program?), but when CPAN was looking for it, it couldn't find it because the permissions were messed up.

Comment: Any chance you can use Strawberry Perl and leave the Cygwin headaches behind?

Comment: You say you have 5.8.8 but it is looking for `perl5.8.7.exe`. Post the `$PATH`.

Comment: Did you check what condition actually displays that message?

Comment: What's the output of `perl -le'print( (-x "/usr/bin/perl.exe") || 0 )'`

Comment: What's the output of `/usr/bin/perl.exe -e "require 5; print qq{VER_OK\n}"`

Comment: Found the problem. ikegami was on the right track. Cygwin was never installed correctly. The permission on Perl were `-rwx------`, and the group was `mkgroup`. Did a chmod, and now everything works just fine.

Comment: @ikegami: Can you give an actual Answer, so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message comes from ExtUtils::MakeMaker. The message results from not finding an executable (-x) that's not a directory (!-d) that can run `-e "require 5; print qq{VER_OK\n}"`.

So, check the permissions of your Perl,

```
perl -le'print( (-x "/usr/bin/perl.exe") || 0 )'
```

and on the off chance that the above returns true, make sure the following runs:

```
/usr/bin/perl.exe -e "require 5; print qq{VER_OK\n}"
```

Comment: The `-x /usr/bin/perl.exe` failed because of the permissions. I didn't think it was a permission problem because Cygwin ran and it certainly wouldn't if Perl wasn't there. I also did a `which perl` and `/usr/bin/perl` was shown. And, typing `/usr/bin/perl -V` also printed out everything just find. The permissions were fixed, the modules installed, and I can convert the spreadsheets. Someone w/ Informatica on their system will check whether Informatica can also run the script.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda late now (sorry, just saw the question), and this really doesn't answer your question, but for situations when you can't "mess" with the machine you're working on much, I've found [portable strawberry perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936185/is-there-a-portable-perl) to be a nice solution for some problems.

Comment: The problem is that this isn't a machine for my use. This is a UAT machine for one of our customers. We use Informatica to execute shell scripts in Cygwin. We needed a way to convert Excel spreadsheets to CSV, so they could write shell scripts to parse the info. I demoed that Perl could do that jus' dandy. However, the install of the required Perl modules didn't work. It ends up that Cygwin was never correctly installed, and the permissions were wacky.

Comment: @DavidW. - Can't say I've heard of Informatica, but yes I got the story  from the comments and your answer. "Isn't your machine" - t hat's why I suggested it; it seemed like a quicker solution for your problems, and you can always take it/or simply delete it afterwards. Anyhow, glad you got your problem solved.